# How to make react native application detect current location using matchmore js SDK?

Tags: location, react-native

I'm using the [js SDK](https://github.com/matchmore/js-sdk) to implement matchmore in my react native application.

The access to my location is allowed.
When I display the **localPersistenceManager**, I find that the location is null and displayed like this

```
location: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0, altitude: 0 }
```

The whole result is like this

```
{ _devices: 
       [ { name: 'Nexus_5X_API_28',
           location: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0, altitude: 0 },
           deviceType: 'MobileDevice',
           id: '20f4a1d9-6c55-49d2-aa7c-5278eec6ccc6',
           createdAt: 1555321201061,
           platform: 'android',
           deviceToken: 'Nexus_5X_API_28_device_token_is_unique' } ],
      _publications: [],
      _subscriptions: [],
      _defaultDevice: 
       { name: 'Nexus_5X_API_28',
         location: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0, altitude: 0 },
         deviceType: 'MobileDevice',
         id: '20f4a1d9-6c55-49d2-aa7c-5278eec6ccc6',
         createdAt: 1555321201061,
         platform: 'android',
         deviceToken: 'Nexus_5X_API_28_device_token_is_unique' } }
```

How can I make the application detect the right location?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the device location manually, by updating Matchmore manager:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
              const location = JSON.stringify(position);
              console.log(location)
              this.setState({ location });
              if (this.manager){
                  this.manager.updateLocation({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                    altitude: 0
                  })
              }
            },
            error => Alert.alert(error.message),
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
          );
```

Once it's done, the publication and subscriptions created on the device will have your current position.